YA book about girl who goes to an alien exchange school
I read this book on my Kindle so I have no memory of the cover, but I read it in 2015 or 2016 (I was in the 6th grade).  It's about a girl who is suddenly uprooted to go to an alien school as their human representative by her grandfather.  Much of the plot is lost on me, but I do remember that there was this tree at the school that only fruits every 100 years or so and the fruit tastes like whatever is your favorite flavor. This wasn't a major plot point, I just remember it vividly.

I wonder if this is Nnedi Okorafor's 2015 novel Binti, where a young Himba woman is admitted to an intergalactic university. I do not recall a tree playing a role in the novel or its sequels, but ecology and alien species with remarkable anatomy may have veered somewhat in that direction.
